# how to generate pb file from proto files in ci/cd gitlab pipeline?

Tags: go, gitlab, continuous-integration, grpc

I am working on CI/CD pipeline (GitLab) build where I need to generate pb files from proto files over CI/CD pipeline.
So in order to install proto compiler all below ways
1.apt-get update && apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler
2. go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
But in both ways I am getting error below error.

protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: can you share your CI/CD file `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to install protoc in your CI/CD pipeline.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2
```

Hit the below command to get env path

```
go env
```

Look for GOENV="{/path}". Copy the path and paste it inside {} below :-

```
export PATH="$PATH:${/path}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**CAVEAT: this is alternative thought to your question as it has already be answered and approved.**

---

If your are generating Go files from `.proto` definitions, then it is common practice in Go to commit those to your repo so that they can be packaged up appropriately if you are building from your CI/CD or creating a module from the repo.

It seems like if you really don't want to commit those files, then you should have a good outlier use case to that end to explain it back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my task proto files were stored in some other repo. That other repo is submodule of current repo. Hope, I am making any sense. That's why I needed to some extra steps.